# (Java) Creating methods for new object created via reflection?

Tags: java, class, overloading

I have abstract methods in a class that need to be implemented by a foreign class in a SEPARATE project that uses my project.

-- All classes instanceof A are initially generated using reflection --

So anyway, say Class A is abstract, and Class B (non-abstract) extends A

B has all the unimplemented methods in Class A because B is in my workspace so I know to add those methods.

C also extends A, but C only has a subset of the abstract methods in A.  C, however, is not in my workspace.

Therefore, for each abstract method in C NOT in A, I need to find some way to add the method for A like so:

(For each method)

```
public <corresponding return type> <missingMethodName>() { return null; }
```

Is this possible?

P.S. Please assume that I either have to completely rewrite my code to be in sync with the objects I have no control over, or implement a solution like the one I am alluding to above.

Comment: How does the code compile if `C` extends `A`, `A` is abstract, and `C` does not implement all the abstract methods?  Also, how would calling `super.<missingMethodName>()` work if the `super` that is being called is `A`, which has no implementation?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Reflection allows you to load classes and call methods. But it doesn't allow defining new methods. You would need byte-code instrumentation to do that. Also, I don't see what workspace have to do with this: a workspace is an IDE thing. It has nothing to do with the execution of a Java program.

Comment: Crap, you're right, it's impossible.  The class would have to implement that before runtime.  Dammit...

Answer (score 0):

No, unless I'm reading you incorrectly, what you're asking for doesn't really make much sense.

If you wanted to inject a method

```
public <corresponding return type> <missingMethodName>() { super.<missingMethodName>(); }
```

into C, which extends A, which doesn't implement that method, what would it exactly do?

If you want to provide a default implementation in A, that's fine, and it won't affect C. If you add abstract methods into A, C must implement them, mark itself as abstract, or it won't compile (or throw serialization, or some weird error) if you run with a C compiled with an older A.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense because the project design for the class and how the autograder works is very poor.  I won't bother going into details... nicholas already made it clear this cannot compile without the unimplemented methods actually existing in Class C.

Answer (score 0):

You should never need to do this as any instance method which has a `super` implementation can be called on a sub-class instance.

You can add these methods using byte code, but the only difference they would make is to change the list of getDefinedMethods(). However it wouldn't change the behaviour of the objects of the class.

Comment: To be clear, this is what's wrong:

- It is logical that every subclass of A have each abstract method in A.  Every subclass I actually create uses all of the methods.
- The autograder object does not use every abstract method in A because it tests things in a way that is not in accord with my design.  (This is their fault for making the students' design dependent on the framework provided.)

Comment: If you want to stub out the abstract methods of an abstract class you can generate a sub-class using byte-code. e.g. ASM. However, writing you own is likely to be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

its quiet difficult but you can do it with [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)

> Javassist (Java programming assistant) is a Java library providing a means to manipulate the Java bytecode of an application.[1](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) In this sense Javassist provides the support for structural reflection, i.e. the ability to change the implementation of a class at run time.
>   Bytecode manipulation is performed at load-time through a provided class loader. 
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javassist